# Selenium Grid Setup for the Test cases those does not contains annotations

Tags: selenium, grid

I have different Test Suite but those does not contains either TestNG or Junit Annotation. I am aware of about the steps how to Run the HUB and NODE.

Since My WebDriver Test scripts does not contains Annotations, how to trigger the execution ?

Comment: Create a main method and call all your test (without test annotation) methods

Comment: Hi Nguyen, I have single Package which has 100+ Selenium script with single Main () File. If i run the Main () class then all my 100+ scripts will get executed. But how to make sure that all scripts are running in different browser with Grid integration either sequential or Parallel. Where & how I should instruct to make sequential or parallel execution.